# Android Keyboard

Tags: android

when i click on edittext, keyboard appears.but the keyboard hides my view.how to resolve this.

is it possible show my view completely when key board appears.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) property of the activity tag.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest add this line:

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</Activity>
```

WindowSOftInput adjust your view while softkeyboard up in android.